# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: docker.io/bcgovimages/von-image:py36-indy1.3.1-dev-441-ew-s2i: not found

Tags: docker

I have set up VON network on my device and currently trying to set up Permitify on Windows 10. After using ./mange build it will shows error like this:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: docker.io/bcgovimages/von-image:py36-indy1.3.1-dev-441-ew-s2i: not found

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Z9E.png)

using docker version 20.10.12
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tag on the `bcgovimages/von-image` image called `py36-indy1.3.1-dev-441-ew-s2i` on docker hub. It might have been removed and replaced with a newer one. I quickly tried finding one that looked like your tag, but didn't have any luck.

I'd try using `bcgovimages/von-image:py36-1.16-1` since that's the newest one that starts with `py36`.

You can check what tags are available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/bcgovimages/von-image/tags?page=1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message after migrating from Docker Desktop to colima.  My docker build was failing:

```
$ docker -v build . -f Dockerfile 
[+] Building 0.2s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine                                                                                                               0.1s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: docker-credential-desktop resolves to executable in current directory (./docker-credential-desktop), out: ``
```

The error message I was receiving is similar to that received by the OC (wpj).

So I solved the problem by downloading the image again:

```
$ docker pull python:3.10-alpine
3.10-alpine: Pulling from library/python
213ec9aee27d: Already exists 
47858aee13bf: Already exists 
cfe0d6c6d05c: Already exists 
2df617b3dcd9: Already exists 
db25826960ff: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:03504748146cea12539306ef7eea0983e282a335bdf565e6becc1bec8535b00f
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.10-alpine
docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine
```

Even though the image was already local to my colima instance, there may have been a reference to Docker desktop meta-data that was causing the failure.  The subsequent pull resulted in this being corrected.

A little bit more insight - my build was working well with colima until I delete Docker Desktop.  Apparently, there was a metadata dependency that I was unaware of (but now can correct).